# Cannot download .pdf file in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, encoding, webclient

I am fairly new to Silverlight.  I am trying to download a .pdf file (and a couple of other formats) in Silverlight.  The user clicks a button, the system goes and gets the URI, then shows a SaveFileDialog to obtain the location to save the file.  Here is a code snippet:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e3) =>
{
    if (e3.Error == null)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(e3.Result);
            using (Stream fs = (Stream)mySaveFileDialog.OpenFile())
            {
                fs.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                fs.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("File successfully saved!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error getting result: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e3.Error.Message);
};

wc.DownloadStringAsync("myURI", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

The file gets saved OK, but it is about twice as big as the original and is unreadable.  e3.Result looks about the right size (5Mb), but I suspect it contains a lot of extraneous characters.  FileBytes seems to be about two times too big (11Mb).  I wanted to try DownloadDataAsync instead of DownloadStringAsync (hoping it would resolve any encoding issues), but Silverlight has a very cut-down version of System.Net.WebClient and does not support DownloadDataAsync (it won't compile).

I am fairly sure it is an encoding problem, but I cannot see how to get around it.

Comment: why do you use encoding? I think pdf files are binary and shouldn't be encoded, did you try to use DownloadDataCompleted ( or write string withoud using encoding? )

Comment: DownloadDataCompleted is not available in the Silverlight version of System.Net.WebClient.  I tried just writing the string but got much the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF files are binary and not encoded using UTF8. To download a PDF file using Silverlight you need to use the [`OpenReadAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.openreadasync%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method of the `WebClient` class to start downloading the binary data of the file, and not the [`DownloadStringAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method as you seem to be doing.

Instead of handling the [`DownloadStringCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringcompleted%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event you should handle the [`OpenReadCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.openreadcompleted%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event and write the received bytes to the stream of the local PDF file. If you set the [AllowReadStreamBuffering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.allowreadstreambuffering%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to `true` the `OpenReadCompleted` event is only fired when the entire file has been downloaded providing you with the same behavior as the `DownloadStringCompleted`. However, the entire PDF file will be buffered in memory which may be a bad idea if the file is very large.

Comment: That fixed it @Martin.  It gets me a stream back, so I just had to go                   using (Stream fs = (Stream)dialog.OpenFile())
{
    e3.Result.CopyTo(fs);
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("File successfully saved!");
}